# Shapefile disappearing in exported map image from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, export, layouts

I'm exporting a map image from ArcGIS Pro, which is made of three overlayed shapefiles.

Everything looks dandy in the layout, but after exporting, one of the shapefiles is not on the map. The legend contains the symbology for the layer, but it is missing in the map frame.

What could be the problem?

I tried exporting in different formats, but it doesn't make any difference.
I'm using one Map and one Layout with one map frame.

Comment: You might run a repair geometry tool on the layer.

Comment: I tried your tip and actually figured out that it was caused by unsaved geoprocessing changes. Thanks!

Comment: I imported a 3d Collada file into ArcGIS Pro and was having the same issue trying to export the layout. Went back to the map and saved edits and it worked as expected.